# R Sweave - text and plots get printet to two different files

Tags: r, sweave

I want to start using Sweave (I'm quite familiar with LaTeX, especially form my days as a student).

Trying to get an idea of how to use it, I'm going through [this intro](http://www.math.montana.edu/~jimrc/classes/Rseminar/SweaveIntro.html).

I'm basically copying their example file (see below) into Rstudio and clicking "Compile PDF".

But what happens is that the text with the R output from tests etc. gets printet to a PDF with the same name as my .Rnw file, whereas the plots get printet to another file called Rplots.pdf.

How do I make it print the plots and text to the same file? I apologise in advance if there's something obvious I've missed, it's my first time using Sweave ever today.

testSweave.Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, verbatim}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{center}
{\bf \Large Stat 500 Assignment 1\\}
\end{center}

Using the rock data in the datasets package. First we do some plots:\\
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.3\linewidth}
<<>>=
data(rock)
require(ggplot2)
plot1 = qplot(x=area, y=log(perm), data=rock) + theme_bw() + geom_smooth(col="red")
print(plot1)
@
%%  lattice and ggplots must be inside a print statement to show up
<<>>=
print(plot1 + aes(x = peri) )
@
<<>>=
print(plot1 + aes(x = shape) )
@

 Now go back and remove the \%\% comments on the line 15 above here  
 to set each plot width to .3
 times linewidth, and the three plots should fit on one line.  If you leave a      blank line between the three code chunks above, they will start on new lines.

Summary of the linear model:
<<>>=
  rock.lmfit <- lm(log(perm) ~ ., rock)
  summary(rock.lmfit)
 @

 <<>>=
 xtable::xtable( summary(rock.lmfit)$coef, digits=5)  
 @
 <<>>=
 rock.rlmfit = MASS::rlm( log(perm) ~ ., rock)
 xtable::xtable( summary(rock.rlmfit)$coef, digits = 4)
  ## assumes that you have the xtable package available. It creates latex     tables.


#To print any R object use a \verb|\Sexpr{any_R_object}| statement like this:
#AIC of the linear model is \Sexpr{AIC(rock.lmfit)}.  
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I don't know why they omitted this in the intro, but anyway adding a "fig = TRUE" statement did the trick.

E.g. in the first chunk:

```
<<>>=
data(rock)
require(ggplot2)
plot1 = qplot(x=area, y=log(perm), data=rock) + theme_bw() + geom_smooth(col="red")
print(plot1)
@
```

All I had to do was add the stament:

```
<<fig = TRUE>>=
data(rock)
require(ggplot2)
plot1 = qplot(x=area, y=log(perm), data=rock) + theme_bw() + geom_smooth(col="red")
print(plot1)
@
```

And now it all gets printed to one file.